# Long press on touch screen does not perform long press action but opens context menu

Tags: chromium, vnc, touchscreen

I have a React application that i am running on Chromium. The application has a portion for connecting to VNC in which i need to perform a long press action on a touch display but instead it treats that action as a right mouse click. Is there a way to rebind or change the action to be a standard long click and not a right click?

Comment: You haven't provided any specific OS/release details; but you've tagged you're using *Ubuntu Touch* or the phone/tablet OS.  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *Ubuntu Touch is supported by [UBPorts](https://ubports.com/) and now called [Lomiri](https://lomiri.com/)*